# PHP class method treats parameter as an object instead of string/dynamically interpreting the parameter data type

Tags: php, object, php-5.2, interpreted-language, loose-typing

I discovered something new today.

I have a PHP class with typical members, private, public and protected methods.

One of the methods is this:

```
protected function processThis($dataString)
{
   $dataStringJson = json_decode($dataString);

}
```

And this spits out a warning:

**json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in .../File.php on line xxx**

Wait a second, isn't PHP loosely typed and dynamically interpreted ?

Comment: have you got a  __toString() method in your object

Comment: ...yes...? That doesn't mean it doesn't have types or that everything magically works with everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it is, but there are some functions where it is better to alert people that they are doing something odd. You'll also get warnings for `$f = "1"; array_shift($f);`.

If you want `json_decode` to just work, then casting to a string is easy enough:

```
protected function processThis($dataString)
{
   $dataStringJson = json_decode(''.$dataString);
}
```